# TextureRegion getKeyFrame Libgdx method error

Tags: java, exception, libgdx, game-engine

Libgdx error show inline 57 that show 
`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;`
Help me how to convert Animation  to TextureRegion idk how to get it. I copied from MasteringLibGDXGameDevelopment_CodeBundle it using libgdx old version and don't get an update from an official website I use Animation  rather than TextureRegion because of update thanks for helping me....

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package RpgGame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.GridPoint2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public abstract class GraphicsComponent implements Component {
    protected TextureRegion _currentFrame;
    protected float _frameTime = 0f;
    protected Entity.State _currentState;
    protected Entity.Direction _currentDirection;
    protected Json _json;
    protected Vector2 _currentPosition;
    protected Hashtable<Entity.AnimationType, Animation<TextureRegion> > _animations;
    protected ShapeRenderer _shapeRenderer;

    protected GraphicsComponent(){
        _currentPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
        _currentState = Entity.State.WALKING;
        _currentDirection = Entity.Direction.DOWN;
        _json = new Json();
        _animations = new Hashtable<Entity.AnimationType, Animation<TextureRegion> >();
        _shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        _currentFrame =  null;
    }

    public abstract void update(Entity entity, MapManager mapManager, Batch batch, float delta);

    protected void updateAnimations(float delta){
        _frameTime = (_frameTime + delta)%5; //Want to avoid overflow

        //Look into the appropriate variable when changing position
        switch (_currentDirection) {
            case DOWN:
                if (_currentState == Entity.State.WALKING) {
                    Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_DOWN);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IDLE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_DOWN);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrames()[0];
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IMMOBILE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.IMMOBILE);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                }
                break;
            case LEFT:
                if (_currentState == Entity.State.WALKING) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_LEFT);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IDLE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_LEFT);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrames()[0];
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IMMOBILE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.IMMOBILE);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                }
                break;
            case UP:
                if (_currentState == Entity.State.WALKING) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_UP);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IDLE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_UP);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrames()[0];
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IMMOBILE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.IMMOBILE);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                if (_currentState == Entity.State.WALKING) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_RIGHT);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IDLE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.WALK_RIGHT);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrames()[0];
                } else if(_currentState == Entity.State.IMMOBILE) {
                    Animation <TextureRegion> animation;
                    animation = _animations.get(Entity.AnimationType.IMMOBILE);
                    if( animation == null ) return;
                    _currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(_frameTime);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //Specific to two frame animations where each frame is stored in a separate texture
    protected Animation loadAnimation(String firstTexture, String secondTexture, Array<GridPoint2> points, float frameDuration){
        Utility.loadTextureAsset(firstTexture);
        Texture texture1 = Utility.getTextureAsset(firstTexture);

        Utility.loadTextureAsset(secondTexture);
        Texture texture2 = Utility.getTextureAsset(secondTexture);

        TextureRegion[][] texture1Frames = TextureRegion.split(texture1, Entity.FRAME_WIDTH, Entity.FRAME_HEIGHT);
        TextureRegion[][] texture2Frames = TextureRegion.split(texture2, Entity.FRAME_WIDTH, Entity.FRAME_HEIGHT);

        Array<TextureRegion> animationKeyFrames = new Array<TextureRegion>(2);

        GridPoint2 point = points.first();

        animationKeyFrames.add(texture1Frames[point.x][point.y]);
        animationKeyFrames.add(texture2Frames[point.x][point.y]);

        return new Animation(frameDuration, animationKeyFrames, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    }

    protected Animation loadAnimation(String textureName, Array<GridPoint2> points, float frameDuration){
        Utility.loadTextureAsset(textureName);
        Texture texture = Utility.getTextureAsset(textureName);

        TextureRegion[][] textureFrames = TextureRegion.split(texture, Entity.FRAME_WIDTH, Entity.FRAME_HEIGHT);

        Array<TextureRegion> animationKeyFrames = new Array<TextureRegion>(points.size);

        for( GridPoint2 point : points){
            animationKeyFrames.add(textureFrames[point.x][point.y]);
        }

        return new Animation(frameDuration, animationKeyFrames, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    }
}
```

this code from MasteringLibGDXGameDevelopment_CodeBundle

Comment: error show in '_currentFrame = animation.getKeyFrames()[0];' inline 57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the Javadoc for `animation.getKeyFrames()`, you'll see that it returns an `Object[]` unless you instantiate your `Animation` with a "type-aware Array". This means when you instantiate the `Array` on your line `Array<TextureRegion> animationKeyFrames = new Array<TextureRegion>(2)`, you need to also pass the type to the constructor, so change it to

```
Array<TextureRegion> animationKeyFrames = new Array<TextureRegion>(true, 2, TextureRegion.class);
```